# How to solve Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, acrobat

I have developed window application by using **Visual studio 2010**.I have distributed this application setup to clients and working fine in all systems but suddenly appears **Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component** error when open pdf file in this application in one of the client's system(Windows 7, 32 bit).

I have tried,

1.Reinstalled adobe reader(10) from adobe reader 11.

2.Adobe reader->Edit->Preference->security(enhanced)->Unchecked :Enable Enhanced security.

3.Reinstalled .Net client profile 4.0

But nothing helps me.

I hope someone will help me out.

Comment: This **might** be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2013/03/08/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component.aspx

Comment: @Cyclone .this error from client system. they are not installed visual studio.how can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for us:
Enable the Adobe “Display PDF in Browser” functionality in Internet options.

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple disable/apply followed by a re-enable/apply of the Adobe PDF Link Helper and Adobe PDF Reader addons will work.